# Is there a standard rule for which face in a family is the default?

Tags: typography

The Avenir family that ships with Mac OS X comes with twelve faces. Avenir Book and Avenir Roman both have 400 weight, normal font-stretch, and are not italicized.

I'm building a product that lets users write text in custom fonts that they upload. Is there a standard way to determine which font in a family should be used by default? Is there some kind of setting in the fonts themselves that I'm missing that would tell me that?

Comment: Book. That should be the standard, default version of the font.

Comment: For this particular font, yes. I'm wondering if I should always favor a face named "book," or if perhaps there's some more general rule.

Comment: I generally prefer "Regular" or "Medium". I find "Book" to be a lighter face. But it does all depend upon what *that* foundry set as "Book", "Regular" or "Medium" and if any or all of them are even available. So, in short.... depends upon the font and what you are after :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Scott, it really depends on what the font foundry decided to name the variants. 'Book', 'Regular', 'Medium' or even 'Normal' are variants I have encountered. Variants named 'Book' may be as heavy as other foundry's 'Medium' and vice versa.

**tl;dr** There's no fixed rule, let yourself be guided by the font face names but don't be bound by them.

Comment: The real trouble starts when you have fonts that have both a Book, a Regular, _and_ a Normal weight (I came across one recently, though I don’t recall what it was). That’s when you start seriously scratching your head.